# BotDetect Asp.net Captcha not working on https -

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, captcha, botdetect

Getting error as "***Captcha.UserInputID is not set. Your implementation of BotDetect is not completely secure yet.
Please add "yourCaptchaInstance.UserInputID = <CAPTCHA_CODE_INPUT_ID>;" line to the code that adds Captcha to this form.***"

The code work fines on http , but when we published code on https domain it is throwing error as above. Sometimes it works for first time and 2nd time it doesn't work until you clear cache or restart application.

Controller

[image: Below is my code in controller]

View :

[image: css and packages]

captcha code

[image: view 2]

route config

[image: route]

web config

[image: webconfig part 1]

[image: webconfig 2]

[image: webconfig 3]

Comment: it would be nice if you post the codes as text instead of image. also, is this `botdetect` an open source? maybe digging there will shed some clue. if it isn't, you should double check cookies and stuff then make sure they behave the same way on both HTTP and HTTPs environment.

Comment: "<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="BotDetect.Web.CustomSessionIdManager, BotDetect" /> " By this seeting of coolieless=true. the issue was resolved. But we are now facing another issue. "absURL() in javascript is not working. So the data we are pssing from ajax is passed as null.

Comment: please post code as text not screenshots. `absURL()` - this deserve a different question, imho. is this angular app?